# Extracting data from column to a new column sql developer

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I've imported data into SQL developer and I need to separate data from one column into a new column.  For example I have:

```
Temp_Title
Congo (1995)
Nadja (1993)
```

I need to remove the year from the title into a new column named `temp_year`.  I was told that I can use "Parse" but I'm not sure where to start.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample, few rows imported

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database you use; also, you mentioned "SQL Developer" (designed by Oracle) but tagged the question with "plsqldeveloper" tag so - actual query *might depend* on certain info you didn't share with us.

Anyway, to get you started, here's an example (based on Oracle) which uses two options:

- the first one uses *traditional* `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination
- another one uses regular expressions

.

```
SQL> with test (temp_title) as
  2    (select 'Congo (1995)' from dual union all
  3     select 'Nadja (1993)' from dual union all
  4     select 'Back to the future (1985)' from dual
  5    )
  6  select
  7    substr(temp_title, 1, instr(temp_title, '(') - 1) title,
  8    substr(temp_title, instr(temp_title, '(') + 1, 4) year,
  9    --
 10    regexp_substr(temp_title, '(\w| )+') title2,
 11    rtrim(regexp_substr(temp_title, '\d+\)$'), ')') year2
 12  from test;

TITLE                YEAR             TITLE2               YEAR2
-------------------- ---------------- -------------------- -----
Congo                1995             Congo                1995
Nadja                1993             Nadja                1993
Back to the future   1985             Back to the future   1985

SQL>
```

Comment: My apologies I should remove that tag.  This is a HW assignment and my professor referenced "Parsing" the data to get the year in a column by itself.  I'm not asking for an answer but just a bit of help to start.  There are over 50,000 rows so I would like to remove all years and the common denominator is that they're surrounded by brackets.  Is there a way to write a statement that can do that?

Comment: If that was the answer to my question it isn't very clear. (No offense) So does the answer you gave above allow me to write a single statement that will go through all of the data in that column and remove all years into a new column?

Comment: Lines 7 and 10 show how to extract the first part. Lines 8 and 11 show how to extract years. You should use these (pick only one pair: 7-10 or 8-11) in your UPDATE statement. I'm on the phone now so I can't do that for you; besides, it is your homework - it would be fair to put some effort into it, don't xou think?

Comment: You're correct.  I will put in a lot of effort not that I haven't been doing that lol.  I'll try it and let you know.  I appreciate all of your help!!!